# Laptop doesn't always charge

Tags: laptop

Hi my DC socket seems to have a problem. When plugged with power cable, the laptop sometimes change and sometimes don't. I need to put the cable at an angle else it wouldn't work. Upon opening the PC, there we no visible burn anywhere. I'm wondering if the problems comes from the socket?

[image]

Comment: It's possible.  The soldered connections can loosen over time, breaking the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Gently clamp the plug to the socket (jack), e.g. with a large rubber band, and wiggle *only the wire* to determine if the issue is there. If it's not, borrow a similar power supply (PS) to see if it charges consistently; if so it's likely the PS *plug* that's the issue. The [plug can be replaced](https://www.newark.com/c/connectors/power-entry-connectors/dc-power-connectors-barrel-plugs-jacks) easily without having to replace the whole PS.

If you need to wiggle the plug from the borrowed PS to get the laptop to charge, then it is likely a broken solder connection from the PC board, which can be resoldered, or a broken jack -- *less easily* desoldered and replaced. If it's just the plastic shell of the jack that's cracked, try cementing it together, without letting the cement cover the metal connections.

To remove the old jack, if need be, it might be easiest to break it open so pins can be accessed individually. It is hard to desolder multiple pins simultaneously, particularly from a multi-layer PCB. If room allows, it might be easier to connect a new jack with wire, and mount it in a new hole in the case.